# Consulta SELECT que omita el primer resultado

Tags: mysql, sql

Con la siguiente sentencia SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Obtengo estos resultados:

| Título | Fecha |
| --- | --- |
| Item A | 2022-02-16 |
| Item B | 2022-01-15 |
| Item C | 2022-01-30 |

Lo que necesito, es que esa consulta me omita el primer resultado (**Item A**), pero no me sirve el operador `LIKE` ni tampoco algún evento con la fecha, esto porque los resultados podrían ser cualquiera, y el `ORDER BY` puede cambiar dinámicamente (podría ser `ASC` o `DESC`).

Por eso solo necesito omitir el primer resultado o fila de dicha sentencia `SELECT`, y mostrar los resultados a partir de la segunda fila, así:

| Título | Fecha |
| --- | --- |
| Item B | 2022-01-15 |
| Item C | 2022-01-30 |

¿Es esto posible? Estuve revisando la función `MOD` pero no me queda muy claro su uso.

Comment: ¿Cuál motor de base de datos?

Comment: Puedes usar LIMIT 1,1000, eso te regresera 1000 registros empezando en el segundo registro (depende de ORDER BY o de el indice utilizado).

Comment: @Sal gracias compañero, el motor es MySQL

Comment: @JhonSilver tiene sentido, como los array que inician en 0? Lo pruebo en un momento y te aviso. Gracias amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con LIMIT...

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1,1000
```

eso te regresera 1000 registros empezando en el segundo registro (depende de ORDER BY o de el indice utilizado)

Answer (score 2):

SQL SERVER

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY fecha DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS // omite la primera fila
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY; // te traera 1000 filas despues de la fila omitida
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo reviso cuando esté en casa. No uso SQL Server, sabes si existe problema?